# usercontrol in a placeholder

Tags: .net, asp.net

I've tried doing the following:

```
        var userControl = UserControls.ProductDetailUserControl();
        userControl.ID = "id_SubProduct_"+productId;
        userControl.Visible = true;
        userControl.ValidationDependentOnControl = productOption.ClientID;
        userControl.ConditionallyVisible = productOption;
        plhDetails.Controls.Add(userControl);
```

throws a null exception

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 var uProductDetails = (UserControls.ProductDetailUserControl)Page.LoadControl("UserControls/ProductDetailUserControl.ascx");

    //set properties     
    plhDetails.Controls.Add(userControl);
```